# MSAccess'03 VBA - Textbox contents are highlighted with cursor movement is UNdesired

Tags: ms-access, textbox, vba

I use VBA to copy a db field to a textbox for editing.  When I move the cursor in the textbox, ALL text to the right is highlighted.  I just want to edit the contents of the textbox as I would with NotePad. I can find NO params to set the textbox behavior.  I use the standard method for opening the form:

DoCmd.OpenForm "Input", acNormal, , , acFormEdit, acWindowNormal

How do I interactively edit the contents of a TEXT(box) field in a form?  I have searched for DAYS for this answer without success.  Thank you for your responses!

Comment: What do you mean by "when you move the cursor"? Do you mean Options-> Behaviour Entering Field?

Comment: If I [tab] to the text box or click the mouse to place the text cursor in the textbox, as I press the cursor control keys to navigate the text, ALL text to the right and below the cursor is highlighted from the insertion point.  How do I get the textbox to act like NotePad?  I do *NOT* want highlighted text as I move the cursor.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...  It seems that some Windows application I was running affected the behavior of the textbox when the cursor is moved using the cursor control keys -- or maybe it's some application that is active NOW that has "corrected" this behavior!  :-)

TODAY, the textbox behaves as a NotePad -- NO automatic highlighting when the cursor control keys are used -- which is all that I wanted!#@$%^&!!

If I ever determine what application on my workstation corrupts the Access VBA textbox, or "fixes" it, I'll write back.  For the short term solution, ONLY run MSAccess and nothing else on your workstation to avoid this problem!  Forewarned is half an octopus...